# image button with drop down menu

Tags: css

i have been trying to have a drop down menu opon mouseover of the "profile" image button.
by using only css, this is what i achieve.

i also added text decoration to none but the underline still exist.

[image: this is how it looks like]

I have also tried using javascript but it doesnt work out for me.
Would any1 help enhancing this?

my html code:

```
<td class="header_button ">
                        <div id="menu">
                        <ul id="Ul1"> 
                                <li >
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" 
                                        ImageUrl="../img/Button/Profile.png"  CssClass="profile_dropdown" 
                                        onclick="btnMyProfile_Click" />
                                </li>
                                <li class="item" > 
                                <a href="#">Edit Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item"> 
                                <a href="#">My Follow</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item"> 
                                <a href="#">My Uploads</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item"> 
                                <a href="#">My Child Profile</a>
                                </li>
                        </ul>               
                        </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                </td>
```

my css code:

```
.profile_dropdown
{
height:75px;
weight:75px;
position:static;

}
#menu ul .item
{
display: none;
text-decoration: none;
background: #222222 85% 55% no-repeat;
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
font-size: large;
font-weight: bold;
color: #9FC54E;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#menu ul:hover .item{display:block;}
#menu{margin-top:-22px;position:fixed}
```

Comment: try putting text-decoration:none; directly on the <a> tag. As for the other stuff, I can't offer much assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add

```
#menu li a {
    text-decoration:none
}
```

Comment: thanks ! is there anyway i can remove the space between the button and words?

Comment: well, i'm not sure, you can try setting `margin-top:0` and `padding-top:0` to the #menu  div, and `margin-bottom:0` and `padding-bottom:0` to the profile image.
I raccomend you to test different css with firebug o chrome inspector (you can change them on the fly :D)